# Dynamodb write performane when withReturnValues as UPDATED_OLD

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement to update few attributes of dynamodb row. I want to know how does internally dynamodb update a row - does it just update the attributes in memory and don't go to disk while update if I don't need old value. Or will it always go to disk and update new value there so it an return old value in no performance loss. Basially will the update performane improve if I remove  withReturnValues  as UPDATED_OLD in my update request.

Answer (score 0):

UpdateItem works when ReturnValues is not set and when it is set to UPDATED_OLD. However, the response is larger, as the versions of the attributes of the item prior to the update are returned in the response. A larger response means it will take more time to schlep over the wire. To summarize, you can somewhat reduce UpdateItem latency if you do not request any ReturnValues, like UPDATED_OLD, as the response becomes smaller.